# Array to string conversion (SQL Error while using json_encode method)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm getting array to string conversion error .
Even I tried with serialize and json_encode method to convert an array to string .
But it didn't work . I don't know whether this issue is for that string or other variables, .
Here is my issue :

Array to string conversion

**SQL:**

```
insert into vehicledetails (vehicle_id, shortName, registration, vehicleType, vehiclemake, modelyear, documentType, dri_id, expDate, notiInterval, `user_id`, document, updated_at, created_a`)

values (w879847, 9e87sdf98, 9s8f7sd9f8, Car, sdjkfhskfh, NULL, Insurance, , , , 9266, ["dfusf9sf89.jpg","9sd8fsudfsd9.png"], 2019-08-07 13:17:41, 2019-08-07 13:17:41)
```

**Controller:**

```
        $request['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
                 $vehiDetails=$request->all();
                 $file = Input::file('file');

                if($file){
                    foreach($request->file('file') as $file) {
                        $exists = Storage::disk('spaces')->exists('FMSuploads/VehicleDoc/'.$file->getClientOriginalName());
                        if($exists){
                            \Session::flash('error', 'File name already exist');
                            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
                        }
                       else{
                        Storage::disk('spaces')->putFileAs('FMSuploads/VehicleDoc', request()->file, $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'public');
                         log::info('document uploaded successfullly');
                       }
                        $array[] = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    }
                }else{
                    $vehiDetails['document'] = "";
                }
            }
                $array = json_encode($array);
                $vehiDetails['document'] = $array;
            VehicleDetails::create($vehiDetails);
```

Model page .

```
class VehicleDetails extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
        protected $table = 'vehicledetails';

     public $primaryKey = 'id';


    //public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = array('user_id','vehicle_id','shortName','registration','morningTripStartTime','eveningTripStartTime','dri_id','vehicleType','vehiclemake','modelyear','documentType','document','expDate','notiInterval');


    protected $guarded = array();

}
```

Comment: This `["dfusf9sf89.jpg","9sd8fsudfsd9.png"]` seems to be the problem, which var is this ?

Comment: @lucaas Even I tried to change that by "somename.png" . Still not working . I'm Wondering what issue is this .

Comment: The code you have shown seems mostly irrelevant, the actual magic probably happens inside `VehicleDetails::create` - so show us the code of _that_.

Comment: @misorude added the model page  . check it

Comment: Hm, okay, then it is probably not actually in there, but seems to be an issue with the data you are supplying. Since you are not modifying `$vehiDetails` anywhere inside the `if($file)` block, it must likely come from `$vehiDetails=$request->all()` already. Now we don’t know what data you are sending, but if this gets you the documents you are looking for in form of an array, you might have to transform the respective property of that object into a string format yourself.

Comment: @misorude . Sorry for bothering. The issue is mine. I'm actually sending the Doctype as select multiple. It takes it as array . So that's why It's showing the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside for loop declare `$docLink = '';`
inside for loop `$doclink .= $file->getClientOriginalName().',';`
below for loop `$vehiDetails['document'] = $doclink;`
Hope this helps as a work around